# Allowing doctrine data fixtures to be load with a specific role in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using FOSCommentBundle and trying to load comments with doctrine fixtures. The thing is FOSCommentBundle is configured to allow only ROLE_USER to create a comment in my project, as below:

```
acl_roles:
    comment:
        create: ROLE_USER
        view: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        edit: ROLE_ADMIN
        delete: ROLE_ADMIN
    thread:
        create: ROLE_USER
        view: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        edit: ROLE_ADMIN
        delete: ROLE_ADMIN
    vote:
        create: ROLE_USER
        view: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        edit: ROLE_ADMIN
        delete: ROLE_ADMIN
```

But while loading the fixtures, Doctrine is not allowed to add them as it must be logged in as ROLE_USER.

Here is my comments fixtures load:

```
//First depth comments array
    $comments = [];
    //Create a data faker
    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
    //FOS Comment manager
    $commentManager = $this->container->get('fos_comment.manager.comment');
    //First depth comments creation
    for($i=0; $i<$this->nb; $i++){
        $comment = $commentManager->createComment($this->getReference('thread '.rand(0, $this->nb-1)));
        $comment->setAuthor($this->getReference('user '.rand(0, $this->nb-1)));
        $comment->setBody($faker->text(250));
        $comment->setState($faker->boolean);
        $commentManager->saveComment($comment);
        $comments[] = $comment;
    }
    $manager->flush();
```

- Is there any role related to doctrine (something like ROLE_FIXTURES_LOAD) ?
- Is it possible to simulate the ROLE_USER in the fixtures ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should probably bypass the fos_comment.manager.comment which is applying a validation logic proper to a "production" environment. What you want is to get your fixtures persisted ? persist them the traditional way with your entity manager ? Doctrine doesn't care about roles in your application, it is able to write anything to the database by its own. It's the manager's fault if something is going wrong here.

```
$manager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
for($i=0; $i<$this->nb; $i++){
    $comment = $commentManager->createComment($this->getReference('thread '.rand(0, $this->nb-1)));
    $comment->setAuthor($this->getReference('user '.rand(0, $this->nb-1)));
    $comment->setBody($faker->text(250));
    $comment->setState($faker->boolean);
    $manager->persist($comment)
    $comments[] = $comment;
}
$manager->flush();
```

If you want to keep on using the FOSComments Manager, you should try to manually authenticate a user like that :

```
$repo  = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository("AppBundle:User");
$user = $repo->findOneBy(['username' => 'a_valid_and_authorized_user']);
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
    $user,
    null,
    'main',
    $user->getRoles()
);
$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
```

Comment: Hi Philippe, thanks for your answer. I can use the doctrine manager but the fos_comment.manager handles others things such as increasing the number of comments in an other entity (Thread), the Thread depth, anestors and so on..